# Swift - how to change layout content in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimage, appdelegate

I try to show an alert when the app launches (a tabbed app)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let welcomeAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Turn on Bluetooth?", message: "Turn on Bluetooth?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    welcomeAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
    action in self.alertServerClient()
    }))
    welcomeAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))

    let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
    alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()

    alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(welcomeAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return true
}
```

In `alertServerClient()` I want to change UIImage like

```
func alertServerClient() {
    let vc = FirstViewController()
    let imgBTOn = UIImage(named: "BT_Button.png")
    vc.btnBT.setImage(imgBTOn, for: .normal)
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work and throw error

`Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Is it possible to change UI content from `AppDelegate`?

Comment: You are creating an instance of `FirstViewController` without UI by `let vc = FirstViewController()`, this is wrong, and your logic on AppDelegate is probably wrong also, not sure what are you trying to achieve here

Comment: @Tj3n I'm trying to show an alert when app launch and setup some UI content. I did try to add code in viewDidAppear() but the alert showed up anytime I switch between tabs.

Comment: Cant you put it in `viewDidLoad`? `viewDidAppear` get called everytime you change tab is normal

Comment: @Tj3n Putting it in viewDidLoad() is too early because layout is not loaded yet so no alert will be showed.

Comment: Then use a `Bool` variable to indicate if its first load the screen or not, after show the alert then change it and use it to know so wont need to show alert later

Comment: @Tj3n Yeah we can add a bool variable in viewDidAppear() to check (it also means the variable need to be reset when the app closes) or add delay time to wait layout loading in viewDidLoad(). I'm trying something different with AppDelegate. If no solution found I will do as your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: Save your Bool to UserDefault, so it wont get reset. Also can use UIAlertView (if your app support iOS 8), it wont need to depends on viewcontroller and can show anytime